# Set my spare disk to be online

Tags: raid5, supermicro, storcli

How can I set my spare disk to be online? I`ve tried /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/e0/s13 set online, but I got an error 255 Operation not allowed.
Thanks.

```
>0:13     13 GHS    - 3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000NE001->2MA101  D  -
>0:14      9 Rbld   0 3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000NM0035->1V4107 U  -
>0:15      6 Onln   0 3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B ST4000NM0035->1V4107 U  -



root@NAS:/opt/MegaRAID/storcli# sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0/e0/s13 set online
CLI Version = 007.0916.0000.0000 Apr 05, 2019
Operating system = Linux 4.4.0-87-generic
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Set Drive Online Failed.

Detailed Status :
===============

------------------------------------------------
Drive      Status  ErrCd ErrMsg
------------------------------------------------
/c0/e0/s13 Failure   255 Operation not allowed.
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a hot spare online. You need to remove the global hot spare status first.

Comment: I have removed it now from GHS and added again, now it is up.